# POST command missing BODY parameters in SSL (https:), but not in http:

Tags: asp.net, json, ssl, post, https

Working on some code that that I inherited from a non-responsive initial developer. My ASP.NET and web.config are at best "dated", thus I'm turning to the community for some help. One of the first things I had to change is to force this website to operate in SSL (https:) as it deals with sensitive data. The program immediately stopped working and I had to make some undesirable changes to code that "already worked". And it still seems broken, and the changes won't make the client happy.

This is an ASP.NET project that seems hand-rolled.

Sending a POST command with some body text that (I think) is JSon setting additional parameters to the POST command such as: "indexID=8379fcd1-5083-4d1c-a6ee-5812f134a505".

As far as I can tell, this works as intended on non SSL (i.e. http: requests). However, when running in SSL (i.e. https: requests), it appears that the BODY (Json text) isn't getting decoded into the HttpContect.Current.Request parameters (which seems to be happening in http:).

However the post_data that I can read from the input stream has the JSon body text (as clear text?) with the parameters, which my 'fix' adds to the incoming HttpContect.Current.Request parameters as a combined dictionary.

[Here is the RAW command intercepted with Fiddler] POST https://vmdev-xpp/BuilderQC/Services/Data.svc/QueryGridResults?typename=ImportReadyForDownload HTTP/1.1 Host: vmdev-xpp User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0 Accept: application/json, text/javascript, /; q=0.01 Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest Content-Length: 378 Origin: https://vmdev-xpp Connection: keep-alive Referer: https://vmdev-xpp/BuilderQC/BREDFileManagement.aspx Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=ehi2ccsdmekvkgegmfh11n1v; .ASPXLMPTest=2226D5725FBC10FBCCD606108CE5A4E32990EEA8FF8A1864496F69874F116D7E1ABF48A8BFD05EE683FE3F456D4475E88A61B19B299CB557209129BD25E87AC38CECA5303C7E2035E64C1F5A4AD2605D8581181A9C7E48680371F83BC7A93D7A63D8748EA4761A608F424578C20127D01DE0E2FBFBD5F079575E86FD506925D541026B7C8713FDEFE108BCEADBFC1DA0 Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin

_search=true&nd=1629052554858&rows=40&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc&QC_ProjectID=14&FileReadyForDownload=1&filters=%7B%22fields%22%3A%5B%7B%22field%22%3A%22QC_ProjectID%22%2C+%22op%22%3A+%22cn%22%2C+%22value%22%3A%2214%22%7D%2C%7B%22field%22%3A%22FileReadyForDownload%22%2C+%22op%22%3A+%22cn%22%2C+%22value%22%3A%221%22%7D%5D%7D&indexID=8379fcd1-5083-4d1c-a6ee-5812f134a505&entity=false

[Here is the post_data I obtained from the input stream, I think that this being in clear-text is suspect] Post_data = _search=true&nd=1629052767566&rows=40&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc&QC_ProjectID=14&FileReadyForDownload=1&filters=%7B%22fields%22%3A%5B%7B%22field%22%3A%22FileName%22%2C+%22op%22%3A+%22cn%22%2C+%22value%22%3A%22th%22%7D%2C%7B%22field%22%3A%22QC_ProjectID%22%2C+%22op%22%3A+%22cn%22%2C+%22value%22%3A%2214%22%7D%2C%7B%22field%22%3A%22FileReadyForDownload%22%2C+%22op%22%3A+%22cn%22%2C+%22value%22%3A%221%22%7D%5D%7D&indexID=8379fcd1-5083-4d1c-a6ee-5812f134a505&entity=false&FileName=th

Here is the incoming HttpContext.Current.Request.Params.AllKeys, Notice the lacking "indexID" among other parameters
[image: HttpContext.Current.Request.Params.AllKeys]

Comment: Why wouldn’t the request be in clear text? Also don’t use `Params`, rather look into `Form` to see what was taken in. Is the `PostParamDecoder` your attempt at fixing things or already existing code? We would need much more information about what the “force this website to operate in SSL” actually means, what was done in code etc

Comment: It was my understanding that https would encode the entire POST command, including the body. I may just be seeing Fiddler decoding the text before displaying the packets.

Comment: However, I have further reduced the problem to the POST BODY data is getting UrlEncoded (on both the working and not servers), but it appears in the once case it gets decoded by the system processing the HttpRequest and not on the other system (getting a JSon decode exception due to processing the url encoded text).

Comment: HTTPS is on top of everything, it encrypts the data in transit. It is decrypted on the web server before it’s given to your code. It’s entirely transparent to the code always.

Comment: Great, now why did the one work and not the other?